# Passing file and object to body in Post

Tags: c#, reactjs, post, upload

I get blob urls and able to create a file for each blob url and send them to backend, however, I also need to pass a bunch of a different object's properties. (these properties are not related to file at all)

The problem is I cannot send them together to backend. Of course I tried to send only one object and passed my form data (file) as an object property but it didn't work. I also tried content-type: multipart/form-data.

Please do not worry about syntax errors.

```
export const sendObjectAndFile = (myObj, file) => {
 return function(dispatch) {
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append('pdf file', file)
    return fetch(URL, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: 'include',
        body: myObj /* If I pass only form or only myObj that works, however, how can I send them together */
    }).then(response => 
        if (response.success) {
        } else {
        }
    });
}
```

To give an idea about how I handle blob urls in backed (I am assuming I passed only files)

```
var myFile = Request.Files;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try formData.append(${property name}, object), then pass the whole form data.

Eg.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("myFile", $("#file")[0].files[0]);
formData.append("title", $("#title").val();
```

Then in C# controller

```
public void Post(HttpPostedFileBase myFile, string title){
// implementation here
}
```